# Must the question be explicitly stated in the body, or can the question be in the title only?

Tags: discussion, titles

Recently posted was [Find the sequence with following property.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2425337/272831)

[image]

My problem with this one is that the problem is never stated anywhere except the title. Should it be required that questions must also be in the body of the post?

Particularly, I am concerned with when the post is unclear and the question is absent without the title.

Comment: I'll just point out that [How to ask a good question - A good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144) has also a paragraph entitled *Your question should be clear without the title*.

Comment: x.x I checked that, but had not noticed. Thanks @MartinSleziak

Comment: As Arturo Magidin was fond of saying: "one does not start reading a book at its spine".

Comment: As an aside, the OP asked 70+ questions and is on the site for 2+ years  hence one can find annoying the lack of context.

Comment: Making sure the question appears in the body and not just the title has been the policy as long as I have used math.se, I think...

Comment: I _also_ find the title unfortunately if understandably vague about the desired property; this case may not be easy to improve, but perhaps something like _Find a sequence with this constraint on the ratio of successive terms_ would help.

Comment: Ideally, a question should have both: a good title to be searchable (and in some cases even findable), and a body containing all the pertinent information. But... if the OP's were geniuses, they wouldn't have to ask questions at all. If I understand the question, and have to decide whether I want to be pedantic or a mathematician, that decision isn't very hard, usually.

Comment: Well, for some of us, we get confused if we read through the whole post minus the title and don't find any questions, so its not a matter of being pedantic to some @ProfessorVector

Comment: "Should it be required that questions must also be in the body of the post?" The word "required" carries with it the notion of some form of enforcement. A moment's thought suggests that no form of enforcement is feasible. Since there is no feasible form of enforcement, there is no point in asking for a requirement. I think all we can do is (continue to) encourage people to state their questions explicitly in the body.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True, perhaps by "required" I meant "make it a valid reason to close"

Comment: I think that just shifts the problem from "required" to "valid". Operationally, a valid reason to close is anything five voters can agree on as a reason to close a given question. But perhaps you mean to include "question doesn't appear in body" as one of the official reasons you can tick when voting to close. Personally, I don't see the need for that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm not really sure what I mean I suppose. But I don't think I've ever seen someone close a question on the basis of "question doesn't appear in body". Operationally, I'd probably close as unclear or use the "other", but I think one would usually be faced with opposition in such an event.

Comment: "I'm not really sure what I mean I suppose." Well, then, I'm afraid we'll have to close your question as "unclear what you're asking". [just kidding] If the question is clear from the title, I think closing as unclear is a bit over the top. Just ask OP to edit the question into the body, or do it yourself.

Comment: I agree the question should be in the body. But I do not see a point in closing a question over only this. Just fix it with a simple copy paste instead.

Comment: I suppose so. Thanks @quid